# Take derivative of an indicator function in the integrand

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following function

$
G(y) = \int \mathbb{1}_{\{y+f(w)\geq 0\}}[g(w)-y]dw,
$
where $\mathbb{1}_{\{x\}}$ is the indicator function.

I want to do $\frac{dG(y)}{dy}$. Note that the functional form of $f$ is too complicated such that I cannot get an explicit expression of the set $\{w:f(w)\geq -y\}$. So can we take the derivative with respect to $y$ directly?

Comment: If you extend the analysis to generalized functions, then $\frac{d}{dy}\left(1_{y+f(w)\ge 0}\right)=\delta(f(w)+y)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta.

Comment: @Dr.MV so in this case, $G'(y) = \delta(f(w)+y)[g(w)-y]-\mathbb{1}_{\{y+(w)\geq 0\}}$ ?

Comment: That is not correct.  To evaluate the functional, appeal to [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function), which defines the Dirac Delta of a composition.